# React Link adding unwanted / (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to add a Bootstrap tab to my project. But when using `Link` from `react-router-dom` instead of `a`, it causes a problem.

```
<a href="#myID">DEMO</a>
<Link to="#myID">DEMO</Link>
```

Checking in the Chrome's console, I found that a "/" is added before the ID, and this makes the tab not working (I manually remove the "/" in the console by "edit attribue" and it works), may I know how can I solve this?

(In the console)

```
Link: href="/#myID"
a: href="#myID"
```

Bootstrap 4 Tab:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp

Thanks all,

Kenny

Comment: Please look at react-bootstrap project

Comment: Where was Link component imported from?

Comment: @amankkg from react-router-dom

Answer (score 0):

`react-router`'s `Link` component designed to work with relative links, so they have to insert these slashes to compose a valid URL.

To workaround this behavior you need to use absolute paths:

**UPD** it's better to use router props than global variables:

```
// props from `react-router`'s Route
const Component = ({ location }) => (
  // render stuff
  <Link to={location.pathname + '#myID'}>DEMO</Link>
  // render stuff
)

// assuming routes similar to
// ...
<Route path="somepath" component={Componet} />
// ...
```

---

Initial answer code using global variable `document`:

`<Link to={document.location.pathname + '#myID'} />`